# Automatically patching PYTHONPATH (when using Fabric tasks)

Tags: python

I wrap function calls within my initialization module with a decorator that patches PYTHONPATH to add current directory to it so I can use relative imports within my modules without worrying about adding the package to PYTHONPATH explicitly (edited based on @abarnert's comments)

```
def patch_python_path(f):
    @wraps(f)       
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        ROOT = os.pathsep.join([os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))])
        if not os.environ.has_key("PYTHONPATH"):
            os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = ""
        if not (ROOT in os.environ["PYTHONPATH"].split(":")):
            os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = "%s:%s" % (os.environ["PYTHONPATH"], ROOT)
        if not ROOT in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(ROOT)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

Here's how I use it:

```
@patch_python_path
def initialize():
    #at this point any code being run has access to local modules through relative imports
    pass
```

Are there any major issues with this approach that I am not aware of?

---

My objectives with this are the following:

- i want to have a self contained bootstrap that a user can immediately use without any additional env manipulations
- i also assume that a user can change the name of the bootstrap package so it's imperative that all the imports remain relative

[EDIT] I'm actually realizing that the problem I am facing has more to do with the way Fabric runs tasks as opposed to pure Python module importing. If I attempt to run a task from a python shell (as opposed to fab task1) all the imports are resolved correctly without any patching required. Running a task through fab causes import errors

Comment: To be clear: You want the user to be able to drop the package into the current directory, without installing it, and use it, right?

Comment: yes. more specifically what I have is a Django based web application that serves as a bootstrap boilerplate. user clones the boilerplate, makes adjustments and it just works

Answer (score 2):

1. `os.environ` is global. You're modifying it, and not modifying it back afterward. So, after doing `@patch_python_path` on any function, you've now done the equivalent for everything else you define after that—including in other modules and in the top-level script.
2. `sys.path` is also global, and again you're modifying it and not restoring it.
3. You shouldn't ever need to modify both `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path`. (In particular, it's the former that you usually shouldn't need.)
4. You're adding `.` to `PYTHONPATH`, but `os.getcwd()` to `sys.path`. If you ever *do* need to modify both, everything will stop working after an `os.chdir()`, which will effectively change the `PYTHONPATH` but not the `sys.path`.
5. Any wrapped function will lose its docstring, name, etc.; use `@functools.wraps` on your `wrap` function.

Those are all just issues with your implementation, without getting into whether it's a good idea in the first place.

The most common reasons people want something like this are (a) make Python X.Y packages work like Python V.W, and (b) allow importing a package from the source tree to work the same as importing it after install, even from the interpreter shell. The former is probably a bad idea; the latter is handy, but there are other ways to accomplish it. If you have some different higher-level goal, you'll have to tell us what that goal is before anyone can tell you whether this is the best way to accomplish it.

Comment: thanks for your analysis. i have updated my post outlining the objetives i am trying to achieve.

Comment: As per your comments. 1 and 2: i don't see modifying environ and sys.path as an issue in the context of a boilerplate used to establish the base for a project (my case). As far I understand the scope for these is a running interpreter instance 3: You might need both patched to insure that both 'import' statements and other python based processes spawned function correctly (e.g. python manage.py runserver --settings=modules.settings) 4 and 5: good calls

Comment: @PhilipNuzhnyy: If you want these to be modified globally for the scope of your interpreter instance, why not do it on import of your top module, instead of decorating functions to do it? It's much simpler (and, on the off chance that one of your functions needs to get called millions of times, it'll avoid a performance problem, but that's less likely to matter).

Comment: this approach does not seem to work in my particular case (ie fabric tasks)

Comment: What do you mean it "does not seem to work"? Does your module code not get run? Does changing `sys.path` not take effect? Or what?

Comment: This might be due to the way fabric handles its business but if i simply include the env altering code at the top of the module (fabfile.py), sys and environ do not get updated properly and hence i get import errors

Answer (score 1):

You might simply add current path to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
def patch_python_path(f):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if not '.' in sys.path:
            sys.path.append('.')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

Comment: Besides the fact that this doesn't actually call `f` anywhere, the OP is already modifying `sys.path`, so I don't think this is teaching him anything he doesn't know. Also, calling it "legitimate" glosses over all of the problems with it, and makes the OP think he's not doing anything wrong.

Comment: @abarnet Thanks for comment. I updated my answer according to your suggestions.

Comment: Your text "add current path to `sys.path" is still something the OP is already doing. (Plus, it doesn't match _your_ code, which instead adds `.` to `sys.path`, but that's a less serious problem.)

Comment: @abarmet You are right, but the rest of OP code is redundant, so  my example is a simpler way to achieve the goal. Unless something is missing in the problem description.

Comment: Well, the problem description is about patching `PYTHONPATH` rather than `sys.path`, and the question is "are there any major issues with this". Just repeating back bits and pieces of the OP's code with no explanation doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In your answer you argue that one shouldn't change the `PYTHONPATH`, so maybe this is not what OP really wanted. Let him decide whether my answer is useful or not.